# Where/How does Windows get it's driver list?

Tags: windows, drivers, boot

When starting Windows in Safe Mode, you can see a list of loaded drivers on the screen.  I would like to know where Windows looks to find which drivers it loads and in what order.

Comment: %systemroot%\system32\driverstore directs the system to the proper driver locations I believe.

Comment: That is the driver store for re installation purposes, drivers are loaded from Windows\system32\Drivers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XP Safe Mode loads the set of Drivers and Services listed at this registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal
```

or this key if you select with networking

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network
```

.

This is not the location of the drivers but the list it uses to choose what driver to load from Windows\system32\drivers

[Source of Information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx#ECAA)